# Is/Should wrapping functions into a monad transformer be considered bad practice?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

Let's say we want to use `ReaderT [(a,b)]` over the `Maybe` monad, and then we want to do a lookup in the list.

Now an easy, and not too uncommon way to this is:

**first possibility**

```
find a = ReaderT (lookup a)
```

However it does seem like this asserts some non-trivial thing about how the ReaderT transformer works. Looking at the source code for Control.Monad.Reader it's clear that this works just fine. But I haven't read any documentation supporting this. However we could also write find like this:

**second possibility**

```
find a = do  y <- ask 
             lift (lookup a y)
```

Similar ideas hold for wrapping `MaybeT`, `StateT`, `State` and `Reader`. Usually I write something like the first example, but most of the time it is really obvious how to write it like the second example, and you might even say it's more readable. So my question is: should code like the first example be considered bad?

Comment: You can also write `find a = lift . lookup a =<< ask`, which is as clear (IMHO) as the second option, but is shorter.

Comment: or use fmap: find a = fmap (lookup a) ask = lookup a <$> ask

Comment: It's crap that they stopped exporting the constructor

Comment: @FUZxxl, they didn't stop exporting it per say, however there is no `newtype State s a = State {runState :: s -> (a, s)}` (version 1.1.1) anymore, but rather `type State s = StateT s Identity` (version 2.0.0). I don't see anything wrong in changing the api like that, and really anything could have changed so to break any well written code, planning ahead for compatability like that seems stupid, but I do think that constructors are more likely to change than `ask`. Almost pointless but still valid =D.

Comment: How true. I really don't like this.  In this case, they should at least at some `RULES` pragmas to turn code like above into the nicer way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current version of the **mtl** library - which is based on the **transformers** library - exports the function `reader :: (r -> a) -> Reader r a` for exactly this purpose when using the simple `Reader` monad. So we see that the design of the library does take into account this usage. Since no such function is provided for `ReaderT`, we can say with some confidence that the officially supported way to do this with `ReaderT` is to use the constructor directly.

I'll agree with you if you say that an analogous `readerT :: Monad m => (r -> a) -> ReaderT r m a` ought to be added to the library. That would be good both for consistency, and for allowing the possibility of changing the internal representation someday without breaking anyone's code.

But for now, your "first possibility" is the way to go.

Answer (score 9):

I think the biggest problem with the first way is:

> If the mtl authors (or whatever transformer library you use), decide to stop exporting the data constructor for ReaderT then it will stop working.  This happened with the State monad in the version bump from mtl 1 to mtl 2 and it's quite annoying.  Whereas, `ask` is part of the official api of Reader and you should plan on it sticking around.

On the other hand, I wouldn't consider the first way wrong.

Comment: The State monad is still available with constructor. I think you mean the `ST`-monad.

Comment: If you look here: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/2.0.1.0/doc/html/src/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html you will see that the data constructor for State is no longer exported.  It's true that you can do lots of things to work around this though.

Answer (score 3):

At least there is a speed difference.

I wrote a [program](https://github.com/fuzxxl/BWInf), which uses a random gen as a state and must generate about 5000000 random values while running. Now consider these two functions, which roll a dice:

```
random16  = State $ randomR (1,6) -- Using the internal representation
random16' = do
            s <- get
            (r,s') <- randomR (1,6) s
            put s'
            return r
```

Whith the first one, the program runs in about 6 seconds, while the second one is much slower, taking about 8 seconds. I can image, that it is similar for reader, so maybe use this one instead of the more clearer when runtime is important. I used the strict version for this.